# What is the proper UX for pressing back with navigation drawer fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, user-experience

Suppose I have 5 drawer items in Activity B.  If I select 2, then 3, then 1, What's the proper  UX when I press back 1 time?  Go back to fragment 3, or go back to Activity A?  I see SO posts  where people add to the fragment backstack, so it looks like the proper UX is going back to fragment 3.  But what if I kept clicking different nav drawer items?  It would take a long time for me to return to Activity A.

Comment: +1 this is a good question and could probably be answered with a single "correct" specification by Google. But you could improve it by making it a bit more readable, maybe add a graphical description or draft of your activites/fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building out the solutions and testing the solutions on a friend. I would also try a solution where a user has a "home button" to return to Activity A. The back button could be set to returning to the last fragment.

If the user is losing any information while navigating back to Activity A and skipping the last fragments then I would consider that poor UX.

Answer (score 0):

I see the overall trend is not adding the fragments to the backstack but going to the previous activity or exiting the app.  The responses here have been helpful; thank you.